# Can Python floating-point error affect statistical test over small numbers?

Tags: python

Can floating-point errors affect my calculations in the following scenario, where the values are small?

My purpose is to compare two sets of values and determine if their means are statistically different.

I handle very small values the usual way in performing large-sample unpaired tests with data like this:

first group (obtained from 100 samples):

```
first item's mean = 2.7977620220553945e-24 
std dev = 3.2257148207429583e-15
```

second group (obtained from 100 samples):

```
first item's mean = 3.1086244689504383e-15
std dev = 3.92336102789548e-15
```

The goal is to find out whether or not the two means are statistically significantly different.

I plan to follow the usual steps of finding the standard error of the difference and the z-score and so on. I will be using Python (or Java).

My question is not about the statistical test but about the potential problem with the smallness of the numbers (floating-point errors).

Should I (must I) approximate each of the above two means to zero (and thus conclude that there is no difference)?

That is, given the smallness of the means, is it computationally meaningless to go about performing the statistical test?

Comment: if you found any of the answers to your question helpful, it is customary to upvote them, and accept one if you feel that it has sufficiently answered your question.  If none of the answers have been satisfactory, possibly we have misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[64-bit floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) allot [52-bits for the significand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Internal_representation).  This is approximately 15-16 decimal places (`log10(2^52) ~ 15.6`).  In scientific notation, this is the difference between, say `1 e -9` and `1 e -24` (because `10^-9 / 10^-24 == 10^15`, i.e. they differ by 15 decimal places).

What does this all mean?  Well, it means that if you add `10^-24` to `10^-9`, it is just on the border of being too small to show up in the larger number (`10^-9`).

Observe:

```
>>> a = 1e-9
>>> a
1e-09
>>> a + 1e-23
1.00000000000001e-09
>>> a + 1e-24
1.000000000000001e-09
>>> a + 1e-25
1e-09
```

Since the z-score statistics stuff involves basically adding and subtracting a few standard deviations from the mean, or so, it will *definitely have problems* if the difference in the exponent is 16.  It's probably not a good situation if the difference is like 14 or 15.  The difference in your exponents is 9, which will still allow you 1/10^6 standard deviations of accuracy in the final sum.  Since we're worried about errors on the order of, maybe, a tenth of a standard deviation or so when we talk about statistical significance, you should be fine.

On 32-bit platforms, the significand gets 23 bits, which is about 6.9 places.

Comment: Good answer! Perhaps you could add a few words for 32-bit platforms as well.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, if you work with numbers with the same order of magnitude, the `float` representation of data is sufficient to retain the same precision as numbers close to 1.
However, it is much more robust to being able to perform computation with [whitened data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitening_transformation).
If whitening is not an option for your use case, you can use an arbitrary precision library for non-integer data (Python offers built-in arbitrary precision integers), like [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/decimal.html), [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/fractions.html) and/or [statistics](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/statistics.html), and do all the computations with that.

## EDIT

However, just looking at your numbers the standard deviation ranges (the interval `[µ-σ, µ+σ]` largely overlap, therefore you have no evidence for the two means to be statistically significantly different. Of course this is meaningful only for (at least asymptotically) normally distributed populations / samples.

Comment: " therefore you have strong evidence for the two means for being statistically NOT significantly different" No! A lack of evidence is not evidence of no effect!!!

Comment: @Scott reworded, to avoid the confusion you are perceiving. The message is that you cannot tell if the two are statistically significantly different, and it is in no way implying that lack of evidence is evidence of no effect. However, this feels a bit of how many angels are dancing on the head of a pin...